How to efficiently manage batch insertions with GridDB using JDBC in a Java application?
I'm working on a Java application that needs to handle a large volume of data insertions into a GridDB database. I am using the JDBC API for database connectivity, and I'm facing challenges with managing batch insertions efficiently. I would like to know the best practices for handling batch inserts in GridDB via JDBC, ensuring minimal memory usage and optimal performance.
Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on:

Setting up JDBC connection to GridDB: How do I properly configure the connection to GridDB using JDBC?
Handling batch insertions: What are the most efficient ways to manage large batch inserts into GridDB using JDBC?
Error handling and transaction management: How can I ensure that the batch operations are atomic, and what are the best practices for handling errors and rollback in case of failures?

It would be great to see some example code that demonstrates the connection setup and an optimized batch insertion process.
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class GridDBBatchInsertExample {

    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:griddb://<host>:<port>/<cluster>";
    private static final String USER = "admin";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "admin";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        try {
            // Step 1: Load the GridDB JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.Driver");

            // Step 2: Establish the connection
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            // Step 3: Create a SQL query for batch insertion
            String sql = "INSERT INTO sensor_data (sensor_id, temperature, humidity) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            // Step 4: Add data to the batch
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
                preparedStatement.setInt(1, i);
                preparedStatement.setFloat(2, 20.5f + i);
                preparedStatement.setFloat(3, 60.5f + i);
                preparedStatement.addBatch();

                // Execute the batch every 100 inserts
                if (i % 100 == 0) {
                    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
                    connection.commit(); // Commit after each batch
                }
            }

            // Execute any remaining batch operations
            preparedStatement.executeBatch();
            connection.commit();

            System.out.println("Batch insertion completed successfully!");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            try {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.rollback();
                }
            } catch (SQLException rollbackEx) {
                rollbackEx.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (preparedStatement != null) {
                    preparedStatement.close();
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException closeEx) {
                closeEx.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

Additional context:

Transaction management: I've used connection.setAutoCommit(false) to manage the transaction manually, committing after every 100 inserts. Is this the best approach for GridDB, or are there more efficient methods available?
Error handling: How does GridDB handle partial failures in batch operations, and what are the best practices for error recovery?

Any insights, code snippets, or performance tips would be greatly appreciated!

It is not entirely clear from your description whether there is any performance issue at the moment, or whether you are doing premature optimization.
If we talk about your code, then:

Don't commit() after each executeBatch(). Only at the end.
Try either not to executeBatch() every 100 inserts, or increase the batch size, at least to 1000.

